# Regex to replace a value between quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to replace 2 variable values in a file. I read the file contents in nodejs into a string. And I need to search for these variables and replace their values.

original string

```
var useStub = false;var serviceUrl = 'http://servicetest.test.com';
```

I want to run some sort of command like

```
var result = someFile.replace(regex, 'http://servicestage.stage.com');
var result = someFile.replace(regex, 'true');
```

After this command I want the output like

```
var useStub = true;var serviceUrl = 'http://servicestage.stage.com';
```

I tried a couple of regex patterns but it didnt get the output I need. I have very little exp with regexes. Can someone help me with this?

---

Got it working finally with help from @FloatingCoder.

```
var text = "var useStub=false;var serviceUrl='http://servicetest.test.com';var hello='sdfdsfs';";
text = text.replace(/var serviceUrl='.*?';/, "var serviceUrl='http://newurl.test.com';");
text = text.replace(/var useStub=.*?;/, "var useStub=true;");
console.info(text);
```

[Here is the fiddle for others](http://jsfiddle.net/JjVzz/6/)

Comment: you want to change servicetest to servicestage?

Comment: I actually want to change the whole url between the quotes and also the boolean value of useStub variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
var text = "var useStub = false;var serviceUrl = 'http://servicetest.test.com';";

text = text.replace(/var serviceUrl = '.*?';/, "var serviceUrl = 'http://newurl.test.com';");
text = text.replace(/var useStub = .*?;/, "var useStub = true;");

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text;
```

This might need more tweaking, depending on what else is in the file, but from what you've given, this will work.

There's a JSFiddle to play with [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FloatingCoder/JjVzz/).

Comment: This seems to work if the replace is done on separate strings. The final output only has 'var useStub = true;'. The other variable got removed in the second replace command. Here i updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/JjVzz/3/

Comment: I tried modifying ur fiddle. If there is another variable declaration like var hello='ss';. the hello variable will also be matched in the first regex. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JjVzz/5/

Comment: DOH! My fiddle didn't get updated for some reason ( IE I forgot to click update :) ) so it didn't match the code posted. Glad you got it working!